# Conditional Insert using SAS Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas, sql-insert

I am trying to add records from one smaller table into a very large table if the primary key value for the rows in the smaller table is not in the larger one:

```
data test;
 Length B C $4;
 infile datalines delimiter=',';
 input a b $ c $;
 datalines;
1000,Test,File
2000,Test,File
3000,Test,File
;

data test2;
 Length B C $4;
 infile datalines delimiter=',';
 input a b $ c $;
 datalines;
1000,Test,File
4000,Test,File
;

proc sql;
insert into test
select * from test2
where a not in (select a from test2);
quit;
```

This however insets no records into the table `Test`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? The end result should be that the row where a = 4000 should be added to the table `Test`.

EDIT:

Using `where a not in (select a from test)` was what I originally tried and it generated the following error:

```
WARNING: This DELETE/INSERT statement recursively references the target table. A consequence of this is a possible data integrity problem.
ERROR: You cannot reopen WORK.TEST.DATA for update access with member-level control because WORK.TEST.DATA is in use by you in resource
environment SQL.
ERROR: PROC SQL could not undo this statement if an ERROR were to happen as it could not obtain exclusive access to the data set. This
       statement will not execute as the SQL option UNDO_POLICY=REQUIRED is in effect.
224  quit;
```

Thanks

Comment: The SELECT will never return any data, i.e. no rows at all will be inserted.

Comment: should it be `where a not in (select a from test)` instead of `where a not in (select a from test2)`

Comment: @vkp please see amended question for error generated when trying that

Comment: you can try it using a `left join`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do the process in two steps.  First create the table of records to insert and then insert them.

```
proc sql ;
  create table to_add as 
    select * from test2
    where a not in (select a from test)
  ;
  insert into test select * from to_add ;
quit;
```

Or you could just change the setting for the UNDO_POLICY option and SAS will let you reference TEST while updating TEST.

```
proc sql undo_policy=none;
  insert into test
    select * from test2
    where a not in (select a from test)
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: @tom...hi, thanks for replying. the above worked. when you say do it in two steps, i am not sure what you mean. is there a way to only add records not already in test without using the undo_policy option? if so what is the syntax for that?

Comment: Updated answer with example.

Comment: ah right, i get what you mean with the first example...i cannot do it like that as the table test in my working code has 110 million rows and im not using a server for processing...what should i use to surpress the warning the second option generates?

Comment: Don't see why the size of TEST makes any difference as to which method would be easier or faster. The second method is essentially doing the same thing as the first but is just using a different coding syntax. The number of records that are being inserted has more impact since the first method requires that you make two copies of those records.

Comment: sorry, i misread your first example. i thought you were suggesting creating a whole new table with 110M rows.